# log4net fails silently when running as Network Service

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a web service that fires off a console application.  The console application contains Log4net.

Code from console app:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
```

The problem I am having is that when its running as `network services` the log4net log file is not created.  The application doesn't fail it just continues without logging.

I need to find a way to detect this and fail the application we can not continue without a log file.   I need to inform the user that they need to fix the permissions so that network services can create the file.

How can I detect this fail to create the file?  The only solution I have been able to come up with is to check if the file exists at the top of the application and if it wasn't created to stop.  This just seams like a hack to me Log4net should be able to tell me it couldn't create the file.

**Update**:

I am testing with the following.  My current testing method is to just set the file to be read only after it was created the first time then it doesn't have access to write to it.  It should fail at this point because it cant write to the log file.

```
string logFile = @"D:\TaskDev\Log4NetTesting\Log4NetTesting\bin\Debug\Test\Log4netTesting.Log";
log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = logFile;
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
log4net.NDC.Push("Test Application");
ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));

var m =  LogManager.GetAllRepositories().SelectMany(repository => repository.GetAppenders()).OfType<FileAppender>();

try
  {
  log.Info("hello Log test");
  }
catch (Exception ex) {
   Console.WriteLine("Log write failed: " + ex.Message);            
  }
Console.WriteLine("Done");
Console.ReadLine();
```

app.config

```
 <configSections>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender">
      <errorHandler type="Log4NetTesting.util.CustomLogErrorHandler" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline"/>
      </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{LogFileName}" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
      <maximumFileSize value="250KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

Comment: Log4Net failing silently is one of its top features. A log system should, for most applications, minimize as much as possible its impact on the application, including not crashing it when the log system fails. Of course, this causes log4net troubleshooting to be less straightforward. You may [activate log4net internal logging](/q/677640/1178314) (or [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/09/27/Log4Net_Troubleshooting.aspx/)) to get the failure cause.

Comment: For us (aka my boss)  failing silently is a very bad thing.  If we don't have a log file we don't know there is anything wrong.

Comment: Failing silently is a very bad thing for business functionality. If logging is, for your app, part of its business, you should probably consider using something else than log4net, which is primarily meant for technical logging, for supervision or diagnosis. Such logging must attempt best effort to impact as less as possible business functionalities, thus failing silently. See [log4net doc](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#reliability), which states it clearly.

Comment: I was unaware of this limitation when we designed this application.   I just found log4net very easy to use and it worked for our purpose since this is a server application that is running automated.   Server admin still needs to know if there are issues logging was the only way to achieve that.

Comment: This looks to me as technical logs usage. Such log being unable to compromise functionality of your logging app is still in my opinion best practice. For the case you mention, your supervision system could be adapted to raise an alert if no log at all occurs by example, supposing your app does not exceed some maximal time interval between two logs.

Comment: My solution below works I can detect that it couldn't write to the file.

Comment: BTW if you have another option besides log4net that would work better. I would love to hear it I am always looking for better ways of doing things.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101903/discussion-between-frederic-and-daimto).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you looked at setting the ErrorHandler for your FileAppender?

You can obtain the FileAppender(s) set in your configuration file using code along the lines:

```
var fileAppenders = LogManager.GetAllRepositories().SelectMany(repository => repository.GetAppenders()).OfType<FileAppender>();
foreach (var fileAppender in fileAppenders) {
    fileAppender.ErrorHandler = new MyErrorHandler();
}
```

Where MyErrorHandler class is somewhat like this:

```
class MyErrorHandler : IErrorHandler {
    public void Error(string messages) {
        // giver error message and abort
    }
    public void Error(string messages, Exception exception) {
        // giver error message and abort
    }
    public void Error(string messages, Exception exception, ErrorCode errorCode) {
        // giver error message and abort
    }
}
```

I am not sure how simple "giver error message and abort" can be as usual you do not have GUI access in services

The FileAppender members are listed here: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/AllMembers_T_log4net_Appender_FileAppender.htm
And IErrorHandler members here:
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/AllMembers_T_log4net_Core_IErrorHandler.htm

you might also want to register an event at `repository.ConfigurationChanged`

Comment: I added <errorHandler type="Log4NetTesting.util.CustomLogErrorHandler" /> but I don't see it doing anything its not throwing an error.   Not sure why I need to obtain a set of fileappenders.   Can you please explain what you mean here.

Comment: @DalmTo I added the code for setting the ErrorHandler too, is that sufficient an explanation?

Comment: @DalmTo it might be an option to start the Service from the installer and do a System.Environment.Exit(N) as "give error message and abort", which should cause the installer to fail. Then your documentation can tell how to react on N.

Answer (score 0):

With some tips from Jens I was able to get this working.

app.config - added this line

```
 <errorHandler type="Log4NetTesting.util.CustomLogErrorHandler" />
```

CustomLogErrorHandler

```
  public class LogException : Exception
    {

        private readonly ErrorCode errorCode;

        /// <summary>Gets the service name which related to this exception.</summary>
        public ErrorCode ErrorCode
        {
            get { return errorCode; }
        }

        public LogException()
        {
        }

        public LogException(string message)
            : base(message)
        {
        }

        public LogException(string message, Exception inner)
            : base(message, inner)
        {
        }

        public LogException(string message, Exception inner, ErrorCode errorCode)
            : base(message, inner)
        {
            this.errorCode = errorCode;
        }
    }

    public class CustomLogErrorHandler : IErrorHandler
    {
        public string message { get;private set; }
        public Exception Exception { get; private set; }
        public ErrorCode ErrorCode { get; private set; }

        #region IErrorHandler Members
        public void Error(string message)
        {
            this.message = message;
        }
        public void Error(string message, Exception e)
        {
            this.message = message;
            this.Exception = e;
        }
        public void Error(string message, Exception e, ErrorCode errorCode)
        {
            this.message = message;
            this.Exception = e;
            this.ErrorCode = errorCode;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Testing it**

```
 try
            {                

                string logFile = @"D:\TaskDev\Log4NetTesting\Log4NetTesting\bin\Debug\Test\Log4netTesting.Log";
                log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogFileName"] = logFile;
                log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                log4net.NDC.Push("Test Application");
                ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
                var fileAppenders = LogManager.GetAllRepositories().SelectMany(repository => repository.GetAppenders()).OfType<FileAppender>();

                var customLogErrorHandler = new CustomLogErrorHandler();  // custom error IErrorHandler. 

                // loop though fileappenders adding the error handler
                foreach (var fileAppender in fileAppenders)
                {
                    fileAppender.ErrorHandler = customLogErrorHandler;
                }
                log.Info("hello Log file");

                if (customLogErrorHandler.message != null)   // if there is an error throw exception
                {
                    throw new LogException(customLogErrorHandler.message, customLogErrorHandler.Exception, customLogErrorHandler.ErrorCode);
                }
            }
            catch (LogException lex) {
                // catch log exception
                Console.WriteLine(lex.ErrorCode);
                Console.WriteLine(lex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

While I understand that failing silently is probably nice for some people.  For my application if I don't have a log file and if Log4Net cant tell me it has a problem there was no way for our users to know there was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to verify that configuration worked:

```
if(!LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
}

if (!LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
{
    var logMsg = new StringBuilder();
    logMsg.AppendLine("Failed to initialize log4net");
    foreach(var msg in LogManager.GetRepository().ConfigurationMessages)
    {
        logMsg.AppendLine(msg.ToString());
    }

    // ....do something with the message, raise
    // an evt to UI, log to OS Event logger, etc....
}
```